# Android - If i give height .7dp. Is it possible?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am trying to give a layout height of `.7dp` to a View to create the horizontal bars.

```
<View
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height=".7dp"
     android:background="@color/horizontalLine"> 
</View>
```

Is it possible? I can't really see any difference b/w `1dp` and `.7dp`.

**If not**. Then how can i achieve the height smaller than `1dp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible?

No, it's not.

> I can't really see any difference b/w 1dp and .7dp.

That's because the system will round that up to 1, which is the smallest size you can have.

> If not. Then how can i achieve the height smaller than 1dp?

You can't.

`dp` measures pixels and you cannot have a fractional amount of pixels.